# Furthering brewing education

Tags: books, learning

I've been through a bunch of books, resources and articles and I'm wondering if there are any specific classes/fields that I can audit.

There aren't any brewing programs near me in the formal sense so I'm looking for college-level classes or something that would benefit my homebrewing and further a potential career.

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: I live in the Midwest

Comment: How far are you willing to travel, relocate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK and US there is a wide range of options available to you depending on your budget. (I know you are in the US midwest, but I will try keep this as widely relevant as I can).

As previously mentioned, UC Davis has an excellent degree program and has a huge number of resources online; also the Siebel Institute in Chicago, IL is highly respected.

In the US there is the Brewers Association: https://www.brewersassociation.org, the industry updates section has a huge wealth of resources on Best Practice, Engineering, Quality etc... and the schools section has a lot of the other organisations I have mentioned in this answer: https://www.brewersassociation.org/resources/schools-organizations/

The American Brewers Guild: http://www.abgbrew.com/ has a range of courses.

Worldwide you could apply to join the IBD: https://www.ibd.org.uk/
It has branches worldwide. You would start off with their GCB, then migrate onto the Diploma then the Master Brewer, these are generally taken alongside work place experience.

University of Nottingham and Heriott-Watt Edinburgh here in the UK have distance learning programs for brewing and distilling.

And, regardless of where you live in the world, I highly recommend getting and reading a copy of this book:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1498751911/

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/1498751911/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498751911)

The Kindle version is £30/$40 but I would recommend the full £120/$180 hardback if you are serious about it, the diagrams and photography are not as good or just absent in the Kindle version.

If you are looking for something to benefit a future career, my first bit of advice would be to send your CV and cover letter to every brewery you could possibly commute to and ask them for a job. There is no substitute in this industry for practical hands-on experience.

Many small breweries would love to employ a hard working passionate individual regardless of diploma or certificates.

EDIT:

Just found [this article](https://allaboutbeer.net/article/beer-schools/), it has a few schools in Minnesota, Michigan, and Illinois that you may wish to take a look at.

Comment: Wow that book looks amazing, thanks for a nicely put together answer!

Comment: The book is excellent, very much a reference book rather than bedtime reading, although I must confess I have read it in bed :)   If you need any further advice please find my website and contact me through it.

Answer (score 2):

In the USA, one of the best schools is UC Davis. Y[ou can take many classes online](https://extension.ucdavis.edu/subject-areas/brewing-short-courses)

Comment: I'm looking for more substance. Almost everything they have online is pretty superficial.

Comment: OK, good you can go to the best brewing school in the country Siebel Institue in Chicago https://www.siebelinstitute.com/

Answer (score 1):

BJCP.org

They have great resources on studying to be a BJCP. While 90% on how to judge beers and to know styles and beer defects, having this as a base knowedge will help tremendously in brewing education.